# How to install a fresh copy of Mojave on a Macbook Air?

Tags: macos, install, mojave

When I do the Option + Command + R, I am presented with several options.  One of those options is to reinstall Mojave from an already existing image.  I don't want to use that image, rather, I want to install from a new image.

For some reason I cannot log in to the laptop.  Is there a way to load an image onto a USB drive, pop it into the USB port, and install from it using the Option + Command + R method?

Comment: What are the other options presented?

Comment: Even better, if you have access to another computer: create a bootable installation USB drive (faster than Internet Recovery): https://support.apple.com/en-gb/HT201372

Comment: Hey @Redarm I don't have access to another Mac.. and all the instructions I've found indicate I need to download Mojave from the App Store.

Comment: `For some reason I cannot log in to the laptop?` reinstalling OSX will not fix that.

Comment: Firstly, welcome to Ask Different! :) At present, when I read your question it's not entirely clear what you're asking. Your title asks one thing (for which there are a number of possible answers), while your question body finishes with *Is there a way to load an image onto a USB drive, pop it into the USB port, and install from it using the Option + Command + R method?* which is another (more specific) question. Could you edit the question to clarify whether you just want options for installing macOS Mojave, or whether you're asking about a specific way you want to do this?

Comment: If possible, it may be worth also adding a screenshot of the options you see. It may also be useful to provide some context around why you don't want to use an existing image.

Answer (score 3):

After booting into [Internet Recovery](https://support.apple.com/en-nz/HT201314) with the following key combination at startup:

<kbd>Option</kbd>+<kbd>Command</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd>

...navigate to 'Disk Utility' and erase the disk
[image: macOS Utilities Menu]

After erasing the disk you may then proceed to install macOS using the 'Reinstall macOS' option.